# Android animate elements to top left and top right

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
        >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:id="@+id/lin1"
            >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Score:0"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"/>
        <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/chronometer"
                android:format="%s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/lin1"
            >
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Start Quiz Now"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/startQuizButton"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frameLayout"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like: [image]

So on the click of button, I want the score text box to move to top left of screen and the chronometer to top right of screen. Plus, the button will disappear and in the `framelayout` a fragment will appear that contains the quiz question.

I've tried the following animation for the score textbox but it doesn't move to any more left.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%"
            android:toXDelta="0%p"
            android:duration="900"
            >
    </translate>
     
</set>
```

Plus, even if I get some animation to work, the box comes back to its initial size after the animation ends. I want it to stay there.
I've done a lot of hit-and-trial on the values but can't get it to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the toX value to "0dp" and also adding a fillAfter ="true". Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html for more help on animations

Comment: Android Resource Packaging: [fq] /Users/rajat.khandelwal/fq/res/Android Resource Packaging: [fq] /Users/rajat.khandelwal/fq/res/anim/move_to_top_left.xml:4: error: Error: Dimension types not allowed (at 'toXDelta' with value '0dp').anim/move_to_top_left.xml:4: error: Error: Dimension types not allowed (at 'toXDelta' with value '0dp').